# Symfony2 collection of forms issue

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to create a collection of forms which consists of 3 global parts and and fourth part containing 3 fields that are allowed to be replicated. Both form names are "search". I've no idea what am I doing wrong but in prototype instead of having the whole form created I get the following:

```
<input type=&quot;search&quot; id=&quot;search_statistics_collection___name__&quot;     name=&quot;search[statistics_collection][__name__]&quot; required=&quot;required&quot;    class=&quot;form-control&quot; ><a href='#' class='add-statistic btn'>Dodaj statystykę</a>
```

View:

```
{{ form_start(searchForm) }}
{{ form_row(searchForm.league) }}
{{ form_row(searchForm.range) }}
{{ form_row(searchForm.season) }}
<div id="single-proto" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(searchForm.statistics_collection.vars.prototype)|e }}<a href='#' class='add-statistic btn'>Dodaj statystykę</a>"></div>
{% for single in searchForm.statistics_collection %}
    <div class="single-statistic">
        {{ form_label(single.statistic) }}
        {{ form_widget(single.statistic) }}
        {{ form_widget(single.sign) }}
        {{ form_widget(single.value) }}

        <a href="#" class="add-prototype btn">Dodaj statystykę</a>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
{{ form_end(searchForm) }}
```

Form class: (relevant parts)

SearchType.php:

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('league', 'choice', array(
            'label'=>'Wybierz ligi',
            'choices'=>array(
                'all'=>'Wszystkie ligi',
                'favourite'=>'Moje ulubione ligi',
                'bookie'=>'Ligi mojego bukmachera'
            )
        ))
        ->add('range', 'choice', array(
            'label'=>'Wybierz zakres',
            'choices'=>array(
               'all'=>'Cały mecz - wszystkie mecze',
               'home'=>'Cały mecz - dom',
               'guest'=>'Cały mecz - wyjazd',
               'half_all'=>'Do przerwy - wszystkie mecze',
               'half_home'=>'Do przerwy - dom',
               'half_guest'=>'Do przerwy - wyjazd',
            )
        ))
        ->add('season', 'choice', array(
            'label'=>'Wybierz sezon',
            'choices'=>Statistics::$seasons
        ))
        ->add('statistics_collection', 'collection', array(
            'label'=>'Wybierz statystykę',
            'type' => new SearchSubType(),
            'allow_add'          => true,
            'allow_delete'       => true,
            'prototype'          => true,

        ))
        ->setData(array(
            'statistics_collection' => array(
                array('', '', ''),
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

SearchSubType.php

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder
        ->add('statistic', 'choice', array(
            'label'=>'Wybierz statystykę',
            'required'=>false,
            'choices'=>Statistics::$statistics
        ))
        ->add('sign', 'choice', array(
            'label'=>'',
            'required'=>false,
            'choices'=>array(
                'gt'=>'>',
                'lt'=>'<',
                'eq'=>'=',
                'gteq'=>'>=',
                'lteq'=>'<='
            )

        ))
        ->add('value', 'text', array(
            'label'=>'',
            'required'=>false,
        ))
    ;
}
```

Please help :)

**Solution**

The subform included within collection has to have other name than parent one. Otherwise it all mess up :)

Answer (score -1):

You should do like:

```
    {{ form_start(searchForm) }}
    {{ form_row(searchForm.league) }}
    {{ form_row(searchForm.range) }}
    {{ form_row(searchForm.season) }}
    <ul class="statistics_collection" data-prototype="{{ form_widget(searchForm.statistics_collection.vars.prototype)|e }}"></ul>   
    {{ form_end(searchForm) }}
```

and also do't forget to imply jquery in your twig file like this

```
  {% block javascripts %}

      {{ parent() }}

      <script type="text/javascript">
        var collectionHolder = $('ul.statistics_collection');

        // setup an "add a tag" link
        var $addValueLink = $('<a href="#" class="add_value_link button button-too-small radius">Upload Pictures</a>');
        var $newLinkLi = $('<li></li>').append($addValueLink);

        jQuery(document).ready(function() {
            // add the "add a statistics_collection" anchor and li to the tags ul
            collectionHolder.append($newLinkLi);

            $addValueLink.on('click', function(e) {
                addValueForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkLi);

            });
        });

        function addValueForm(collectionHolder, $newLinkLi) {
            // Get the data-prototype we explained earlier
            var prototype = collectionHolder.attr('data-prototype');

            // Replace '__name__' in the prototype's HTML to
            // instead be a number based on the current collection's length.
            var newForm = prototype.replace(/__name__/g, collectionHolder.children().length);

            // Display the form in the page in an li, before the "Add a tag" link li
            var $newFormLi = $('<li></li>').append(newForm);
            $newLinkLi.before($newFormLi);
        }

    </script>
  {% endblock %}
```

For more details you may follow [How to Embed a Collection of Forms](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_collections.html) .

Comment: Nope, not working. U haven't changed anything in the code except for removing the for loop for displaying current content. I am still getting single input field in prototype.